# Return array's element thst is not set?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array $lang containing several keys=>values
$lang['Contacts'] = 'Kontakte'; etc

how can I grab the array's key's name ('Contacts') IF THE VALUE IS NOT SET and the array element is not in array at all.

example of what I need and what doesn't work:

```
function lang($txt)
{
    global $lang;
    return isset($lang[$txt]) ? $lang[$txt] : $txt;
}
```

so when I try to use this function with an array that is not set (not in the array at all) it does nothing.

```
$abc = lang($lang['RETURN ME!!!!!']);
echo $abc;
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you get something that doesn't exist?

Comment: `$abc = lang('RETURN ME!!!!!');`?

Comment: It exists - I need to echo 'RETURN ME!!!!!' 
I believe it should work. I am pretty sure there's a workaround.. it just happened so that I have no clue how to do that =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your code, the correct call would be:

```
$abc = lang('RETURN ME!!!!!');
echo $abc;
```

Echos `'RETURN ME!!!!!'`, if it is not a key in the array.

Comment: Hooray! Thanks, mate! and thanks , Minitech! Poor brain of mind! Darn. I owe you one, guys!